# Generate all possible non-repeating integers from 1 to limit

Tags: c, recursion, integer, user-input

I'm having a hard time changing up this program. The algorithm is correct already for generating the non-repeating lists. However, I want the list to be generated from a range of the user's integer. (1 to n)

Ex: user inputs 5 -> prints (1 2 3 4 5) then asks for 5 integers to generate the combination(s).

How would I change this so that the combinations are found from (1-n) instead of individually entering the integers n times? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
(Sorry if it's messy, I'm a student :P)

```
#include<stdio.h> stdio.h
#include<stdlib.h> stdlib.h

int a1[50], a2[50]; // arrays
int count=-1, range;
int w; // user defined variable

void main()
{ 

    printf("Please enter a number. (1-10): ");
    scanf("%d", &w);

    int x,y; // comparing
    printf("You have entered %d\n\n",w);
    for(range=1; range<=w; range++){
        printf("%d", range);
        printf(" ");
    } // end for "range"

    printf("\n");

    for(x=0; x<w; x++){

        a1[x]=0;
        y=x+1;
        scanf("%d\n\n" ,&a2[y]); 

    }// end for 

    combo(w);

} // end main


combo(int z) // function with algorithm to find combonations 
{
    while (w<1 || w>10){

        printf("\nThat number is not in range. Please try again. \n\n");
        printf("Please enter a number. (1-10): ");
        scanf("%d", &w);

    } // end while

    int x;
    a1[z]=++count;

    if(count==w){

        for(x=0; x<w; x++)
        printf("%2d",a2[a1[x]]);
        printf("  ");

    } // end if 

    for(x=0; x<w; x++)
    if(a1[x]==0)
    combo(x);
    count--;
    a1[z]=0;

} // end "combo"
```

Comment: the explanation is unclear. what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Aniket 
I'm trying to use scanf to receive a single integer(n). Then from that integer, generate all the possible combinations between 1 to n.
I don't know how to get that list to be recognized by scanf though.

Comment: give us examples of expected outputs with supposed inputs

Comment: (n==3) = (1 2 3)
123 132 231
312 213 321
-OR-
(n==5) = (1 2 3 4 5)
12345 12354 32451 
34215 25431 12543 etc.

Comment: what is 123? @AverageCS

Comment: My mistake I hit "enter" early. Edited.^^

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap (int *X, int *Y)
{
  int temp;
  temp = *X;
  *X = *Y;
  *Y = temp;
}

void print_array(int *a, int n) {
   int i; 
   printf("\t=>  ");
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
     printf("%d, ", a[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}

void mixmatch (int *Arr, int i, int n)
{
  int j;
  int *A = Arr;
  if (i == n)
     print_array(A,n+1);
  else
  {
     for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
     {
        swap((A+i), (A+j));
        mixmatch(A, i+1, n);
        swap((A+i), (A+j));
     }
  }
}

int main()
{
   int A[10];
   int k;
   int i;
   printf("Enter a number between (1-10):");
   scanf("%d", &k);
   for(i = 0; i < k && i < 10; i++) {
       printf("%d, ",i);
       A[i] = i; 
   }
   printf("\n");
   mixmatch(A, 0, k-1);
   return 0;
}
```

This is how you can modify it to incorporate integers and arrays of them.

Comment: How would I do the same with integers only?

Comment: Masterfully done. I have learned a great deal from this. Thank you very much!